# How to get such pattern matching of regular expression in lex

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

Hi I want to check a specific pattern in regular expression but I'm failed to do that. Input should be like

*noun* *wordname*:*wordmeaning*

I'm successful getting *noun* and *wordname* but couldn't design a pattern for word meaning. My code is :

```
int state;
char *meaning;
char *wordd; 

^verb   { state=VERB; }
^adj    { state = ADJ; }
^adv    { state = ADV; }
^noun   { state = NOUN; }
^prep   { state = PREP; }
^pron   { state = PRON; }
^conj   { state = CONJ; }

//my try but failed
[:\a-z]   {
meaning=yytext;
printf(" Meaning is getting detected %s", meaning);

}

[a-zA-Z]+  {
word=yytext;

}
```

Example input:

```
noun john:This is a name
```

Now `word` should be equal to `john` and `meaning` should be equal to `This is a name`.

Comment: Maybe you need to use states.  In the normal state, you treat each word separately.  In the 'definition' state, entered when a ':' is detected and exited when a newline is detected, you collect all characters (except the newline) to create the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing that lex states (also known as *start conditions*) are the way to go (odd, but there are no useful tutorials).

Briefly:

- your application can be organized as states, using one for "noun", one for "john" and one for the definition (after the colon).
- at the top of the lex file, declare the states, e.g.,

  `%s TYPE NAME VALUE`
- the capitals are not necessary, but since you are defining constants, that is a good convention.
- next to the patterns, put those state names in `<` `>` brackets to tell lex that the patterns are used only in those states.  You can list more than one state, comma-separated, when it matters.  But your lex file probably does not need that.
- one state is predefined: `INITIAL`.
- your program switches states using the `BEGIN()` macro, in actions, e.g.,

  `{ BEGIN(TYPE); }`
- if your input is well-formed, it's simple: as each "type" is recognized, it begins the `NAME` state.
- in the `NAME` state, your lexer looks for whatever you think a name should be, e.g.,

  `<NAME>[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]+  { my_name = strdup(yytext); }`
- the name ends with a colon, so

  `<NAME>":"  { BEGIN(VALUE); }`
- the value is then everything until the end of the line, e.g.,

  `<VALUE>.*  { my_value = strdup(yytext); BEGIN(INITIAL); }`
- whether you switch to `INITIAL` or `TYPE` depends on what other things you might add to your lexer (such as ignoring comment lines and whitespace).

Further reading:

- [Start conditions](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_11.html) (flex documentation)
- [Introduction to Flex](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~bvz/cs461/notes/flex/)